# How to link Asp.NET Button with Code-behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on an ASP.NET page with a few different bits of functionality. My first button works just fine, and looks like this:

```
<form method="post">
    <h2>View an Existing Reservation</h2>
   <p><sub>Or just enter your email to recover your reservations</sub></p>
   <div>
       <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                  <label for="name">Reservation ID:</label>
                  <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="ID" Name="ID"  CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox><br />
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                  <label for="email">Email</label>
                  <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Email" TextMode="Email" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox><br />
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row justify-content-around">
            <asp:Button ID="Button2" Text="Edit" onclick="Button2_Click" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary"/>

      </div>
</div>

</form>
```

with the code behind of:

`public void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){}`

In the next button,  I had the exact same setup, replacing "Button2" with "Button3." SO just doesn't allow me to post too much code at once.

The page doesn't access the code behind.

What I have Tried so far:

- using Button3 to try accessing Button2_Click(). This does not work either (i.e., no function runs)
- using "OnClick" instead of "onclick." This also does not run the function.
- Checking the designer.cs - all of my designer.cs files simply show an empty partial class, and all work just fine. I'm updating them using the VS2019 compiler.

Is there anything missing from the second button that needs to be there?

## EDIT:

I solved the problem by simply changing how I was doing it (i.e., conditional logic in Button2_Click() to have different behavior based on input). If anyone wants to take a crack at the root problem to help anyone with this problem in the future, be my guest.

Comment: Probably the designer.cs file is not getting updated?

Comment: How did you update the file? In Visual Studio?

Comment: What happens when you click on the button? Do you get an error? Does a postback occur?

Comment: Hi. Are you using `UpdatePanel`? Could you show us parts of *aspx* page where these buttons are, including enclosing *div*s/*controls*?

Comment: @PabloCG all of my designer.cs files show empty partial classes and work just fine. They stay that way through runtime

Comment: @mason the file is updated in VS2019 for an ASP.NET WebForm project. I get the postback (since it's wrapped in a form, however I do not get an error or any other feedback (it doesn't even enter the function)

Comment: @awsirkis Add the solution as answer. It will be upvoted and free for others to use.

Comment: @MarkoRadivojević it's a non-answer more than a solution, but I posted it anyway

Comment: Why do you have `<form method="post">` ? Form within a form is a bad idea.

Comment: @mason because when I tried submitting without putting them in separate forms, it was submitting the whole page when I just needed a double and string. I wanted to save on bandwidth (mobile-friendly). It may be me getting to used to SPA/SSR, but doing the whole page started to seem way too slow

Comment: Hah, well if you were interested in speed and efficiency, then Web Forms was a poor choice. Web Forms expects there to be a single form, and that form must have the `runat ="server"` attribute, and usually this form is on a master page. Adding additional forms (so long as they don't have the `runat="server"` attribute) is possible but is ultimately going to result in the kind of issues you're running into now. If it's not too late, try to switch off Web Forms. Otherwise just deal with the slowness or code around it (for example, by using JS to post these values to the server instead of a form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really an answer to the root of the question, but if you have two forms operating on the same (or less than each other) inputs, then depending on your business needs, this will work:

```
<form method="post">
    <h2>View an Existing Reservation</h2>
   <p><sub>Or just enter your email to recover your reservations</sub></p>
   <div>
       <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                  <label for="name">Reservation ID:</label>
                  <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="ID" Name="ID"  CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox><br />
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                  <label for="email">Email</label>
                  <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Email" TextMode="Email" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox><br />
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row justify-content-around">
            <asp:Button ID="Button2" Text="Edit" onclick="Button2_Click" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary"/>

      </div>
</div>

</form>
```

```
public void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var keys = Request.Params.AllKeys;

           double id = Request.Form["ctl00$MainContent$ctl00$ID"] != "" ? double.Parse(Request.Form["ctl00$MainContent$ctl00$ID"].ToString()) : -1;

            string email = Request.Form["ctl00$MainContent$ctl00$Email"].ToString();
            if(id == -1) // some default value if the field is left empty
            {
                resend(email); // the function supposed to be run by the smaller form
                return;
            }
            var obj = Request.Form;
            Response.Redirect(String.Format("View.aspx?id={0}&email={1}", id, email));
        }
```

Basically, by seeing if the value not required for the smaller form (in this case, the resend() function) is empty, we see what the user's intent was - by inputting both values, they get one function, and by only submitting one value, they get another function. This is scalable to as many functions as you want, although it'd start to be a pain eventually.